# How should this microwave shelf be stabilized?

Tags: carpentry, shelving

My first post here.

I've spent some time making a little shelf for my microwave oven. I'd estimate that it weighs around 15 Kgs.

I made a plywood shelf with 4 wall brackets supporting it. The edge brackets have cross members and the middle brackets are plain L clamps. Here are two pictures.

[image: microwave on the shelf]
[image: Clamps below the shelf]

The screws which fit the whole thing onto the wall are 2" masonry screws fixed with fischer wall plugs. Each clamp has two screws that fix it onto the wall and two screws that hold it to the body of the shelf. These are 1" self boring screws.

Since the whole thing is like a cantilever arrangement, there is a bit of play when I open and close the microwave. Apart from that, it feels stable. Also, I initially used 1" screws to fix the thing onto the wall and it wasn't enough. Because of this, I'm still not totally confident about it.

I'd appreciate any comments on how I can strengthen it and how I can check whether it'll be strong enough.

My kitchen is quite small so putting something like this gives me valuable space.

Comment: The middle two brackets probably aren't doing much. Make sure it can't slide forward and remember it's not just the weight of the microwave - it's the 5kg casserole you put in it.

Comment: I'll do something about it sliding forwards. Apart from that, do you think it looks strong enough?

Comment: How stiff is the angle support on the outer brackets? Those look pretty flimsy. I'd maybe swap those for shelf brackets that use a vertical metal angle support rather than the horizontal one. Another idea: instead of a wall-mounted shelf, make a wooden box for it to sit on. Underneath could be used as an appliance garage (if you have other appliances you need to tuck away.)

Comment: Can you point me to a picture of the brackets you're recommending? The outer brackets are quite strong but since they're attached to the wall, the whole thing shakes slightly when pressure is applied which is why I'm a little worried. As for the box idea, I thought of that but with that, I can't use the space for another appliance (e.g. a grinder) but only for storage.

Comment: Since you have the shelf in the corner, and you've mentioned movement of the shelf as a concern, I would attach one bracket to each wall. Because there's a window (what appears to be a window, at any rate!) on that wall, you should have some sturdy framing to attach to as well.

Comment: That is definitely a shelf.

Comment: I let the thing stand overnight and saw that the brackets had started to come off the wall by morning so it's definitely not strong enough.

Comment: Put on table or add a leg to outside corner.

Answer (score 5):

Heavy duty shelf brackets - supposed support 1000lbs (450kg !)
[image]

Comment: I should hunt around for a pair of those and if I can't find them, get a pair made. Thanks!

Comment: There is also a type (can't find an image) which don't have the cross bar but are made from folded metal so they have depth (and stiffness) - usually grey steel and used industrially so very cheap

Comment: I have a pair of these supporting a 2x12 shelf in my garage. My fatass has hung from it to test the brackets and the concrete anchors I drilled into the wall and it didn't budge an inch. I also recommend these.

Answer (score 1):

Consider fitting between (possibly seperating) two cupboards so a shelf can sit nicely between, further secured to the cupboards left and right to ensure a strong platform...

Answer (score 0):

wall mounted microwave oven brackets are available in India on ebay.in,they are pretty strong and easy to install and look beautiful as well , I think you should get one of those.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail, maybe a photo of the brackets you're talking about?